# Is possible to use ESP-NOW in LR mode (long range) simultaneously with WIFI STA (to connect to internet over wifi)

Tags: wifi, esp32

I am building esp-now gateway with mqtt but need long distance (200 meters).
I try to use LR mode but when I enable de LR mode I lost connection with WiFi.

Is licit to make use of LR and STA at the same time?

Comment: Are you able to use ESP-NOW at all together with Wifi? I thought this is mutual exclusive, since the same hardware is used for both

Comment: Yes but not in LR mode

Comment: you can use both by switching back and forth, but adding a 2nd ESP tied to serial is probably better to avoid message delivery delays.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily use both ESPnow and WiFi - you just configure it as WiFi.mode(WIFI_MODE_APSTA);
no need to switch between AP and STA
And I have not experienced any delays for my gateway - sending MQTT message over WiFi to MQTT broker takes 6ms